# Kendo Calendar Height Issue

Tags: c#, html, css, model-view-controller, kendo-ui

I want my kendo calendar to be wide but short, every time I try and set the height it dosnt work or cuts off the bottom of the calendar.

The code for my calendar is below:

```
<div id="calendar" class="col-lg-12 is-hidden stockWindow" align="center" hidden>

            @(Html.Kendo().Calendar()
            .Name("WeekPicker")
            .Events(e => {
                e.Change("cal");
              })
            .Footer(false)
            .HtmlAttributes(new { style= "width: 40%;" })
            )
        </div>
```

css:

```
.stockWindow {
align-items: center;
height: 0px;
}
```

Image of issue:

[image]

Image of issue using z-index: 1000; :

[image]

When I try to change the height of the calendar inside of the .HtmlAttributes, the inside of the calendar dosnt scale, meaning that rows of days get cut off.

Comment: Do you have a live example?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add the picture, but no I don't have a live example. You see how the grid overlaps it? That's the issue there.

Comment: Can you try adding `z-index: 1000;` to the `.stockWindow` class or may be in `.HtmlAttributes(new { style= "width: 40%;z-index: 1000;" })` ?

Comment: Updated my question with the result of your additions. It now overlaps the grid, is there a way to limit the height of the calendar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed the issue using the following code:

For the grid:

```
<div id="calendar" class="col-lg-12 is-hidden stockWindow" align="center" hidden>

            @(Html.Kendo().Calendar()
            .Name("WeekPicker")
            .Events(e => {
                e.Change("cal");
              })
            .Footer(false)
            .HtmlAttributes(new { style= "width: 40%; z-index: 1000;" })
            )
        </div>
```

css:

```
.k-tabstrip .k-content {
min-height: 0px !important;
overflow: auto !important;
}

.stockWindow {
align-content: center;
height: 0px;
}
```

When I inspected the calendar I found that '.k-tabstrip .k-content' were making the day cells way too big and so I set them in my css file to override them.